# Using Karma in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, commonjs

This is newbie question, but I could NOT find its answer on StackOverflow.

I am trying to use Karma in Webstorm.  In my Spec file I am trying to require
dependent files, but 'require' itself is not defined!

It is running in Chrome under webstorm control.  Here is my Karma.conf.js file and my Spec.js file.

The basic problem is that 'define', 'require', and 'requirejs' are all UNDEFINED.  So how can I include any of them?!

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jul 19 2016 23:26:58 GMT-0700 (PDT)

requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs(["node-and-require"]);
requirejs("/ob/proj/uniformjs/main");



module.exports = function(config) {


  requirejs("/ob/proj/uniformjs/main");

  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: 'js',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'spec/**/*Spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // spec results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

lexcore/SimpleUnitSpec.js

```
describe("A Unit", function () {
    var u;    // The unit being tested
    beforeEach(function(){
        var requirejs = require("requirejs");
        var SimpleUnit = requirejs("lexcore/SimpleUnit");
        u = SimpleUnit();
    });


    it("to be created and defined", function(){
        expect(u).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Generates this error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Suite.<anonymous> (....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript.

You have three options:

Use  tag.
Use a CommmonJS implementation. Synchronous dependencies like Node.js
Use an AMD implementation.

```
npm install requirejs
```

This option will install the latest release.
Download r.js

If you prefer to not use npm, you can get r.js directly:

Download r.js from the the [download page](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#rjs) and place it in your project.
Get the source from the [r.js repo](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js) and either generate the r.js via "node dist.js", or grab a snapshot from the dist directory.

Usage

These instructions assume an npm installation of 'requirejs'. If you are using the r.js file directly, replace require('requirejs') with require('./path/to/r.js'). 
Basic usage is: `require('requirejs')`
Pass the main js file's "require" function in the configuration to requirejs.

Example:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
//Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
//function to requirejs so that node modules
//are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
nodeRequire: require
```

});

```
requirejs(['foo', 'bar'],
function   (foo,   bar) {
//foo and bar are loaded according to requirejs
//config, but if not found, then node's require
//is used to load the module.
});
```

Comment: Thennarasan, I promise I have spend 4+ hours digging online before asking my next question here:  I am trying to execute a karma/jasmine unit-test which must "require" the relevant source file.  Karma will run, but "require" itself is not defined, so it is not possible to define requirejs using it?!     WEBSTORM is launching the test inside a Chrome browser as it should, but then require is not defined there!

Comment: I updated my original question above is all source files I could imagine showing you.  Somehow chrome is being loaded in a way that require is not loaded!  but I am configuring Karma and Webstorm according to tutorials...

Comment: Let me try to load all your sources in my local and get back to you.

Comment: Thennarasan,  I got it working.  Thanks you so much for your selfless efforts!!  I am going to select your answer since I think it provides valuable info.  I will also answer the question myself too, since the particular fix I found was to add requirejs as a framework for karma, then to refactor my files to use requirejs format.   thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think Thennarasan's answer may work, so I left it selected.

But here is how I managed to solve my own problem:

(1) During running of karma init I specified use of requirejs
(2) I refactored my code to use the requirejs format

The issue at play is that 'require' does not exist in the browser,
and Karma is injecting your node code into the browser.